# Count several rows as one if the next row also are less then a value

Tags: mysql

I want to count all rows that are less then 10 in column "value" but if the next rows also have a value less then 10 only count it as 1(as a group).
So in this exampel I would like to get back the number 3.
I use **mysql**

So id-2 with value(3) < 10 = +1
Id-4,5,6 value < 10 = +1
Id-9 value < 10 = +1

```
-- id -- value --
|.. 1 ..|.. 11 ...|
|.. 2 ..|... 3 ...|
|.. 3 ..|.. 12 ...|
|.. 4 ..|... 2 ...| 
|.. 5 ..|... 1 ...|
|.. 6 ..|... 3 ...|
|.. 7 ..|.. 15 ...|
|.. 8 ..|.. 24 ...|
|.. 9 ..|... 5 ...|
|. 10 ..|.. 15 ...|
```

Comment: Can you also add "count value" to your table?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(value) FROM foo WHERE value < 10 GROUP BY value` maybe? or did I misunderstand

Comment: *So in this exampel I would like to get back the number 3.* why 3? if I got your goal 1- 11, 2-12, 3 - (15,24), 4-15 so we have count = 4 ??

Comment: Less than 10, so row with id 2 (+1) id 4,5,6 (+1) id 9 (+1) = 3.

Comment: @user3800924 Feel free to edit your question

Comment: @user3800924 you mean that **consecutive** numbers less than 10 will be counted as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with variables.  I would do it in a verbose way, by first putting the previous value in and then doing the logic in an outer query:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             if(@pp := @prev,
                if(@prev := value, @pp, @pp)
               ) as prev_value
      from table t cross join
           (select @prev := NULL) vars
      order by id
     ) t
where value > 10 and (prev_value is null or prev_value < 10);
```

The strange syntax for setting the variables is because the expression needs to fit in one expression (MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`).  This stashes the current previous value in a new variable, then sets the `@prev` variable to the current value, and returns the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0f1e/3

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.i=1,1,0))
FROM(
SELECT IF(`value`>= 10, @i:=0, IF( @i=0,@i:=1,@i:=@i+1)) i
FROM table1
ORDER BY id) t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @LastVal=NULL;
SET @Count=0;
SELECT @Count:=IF(@LastVal IS NULL OR (Val<10 AND Val!=@LastVal) , @Count:=@Count+1, @Count:=@Count) CountIncrementLogic, @LastVal :=Val AssignmentToLastVal FROM Table
WHERE Val<10;


SELECT @Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to join the table on itself and lead it by 1 on the join. This only works if the Id's are sequential and there are no missing Id's. If there are missing Id's then each table could be turned into a subquery with the rank function used to join instead.

The following code checks the value and then checks the previous row's value. If the current row is less than 10 and the previous row is not less than 10 then it is counted in the overall total.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b82fb/22

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN c.IsRowLessThan10 = 1 
  AND IFNULL(c.IsNextRowLessThan10,0) = 0 THEN 1 END) AS CountTotal
FROM (SELECT 
        a.Id, 
        CASE WHEN a.Value < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsRowLessThan10,
        CASE WHEN b.Value < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsNextRowLessThan10
      FROM TableName AS a
      LEFT JOIN TableName AS b
        ON b.Id + 1 = a.Id
    ) c
```